# Adding codegen flags to a Cargo build

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

On Macintosh, to allow some symbols to go unlinked, it is necessary to pass `-C link-args='-Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup'` to the Rust compiler. One needs to do this when building Postgres plugins, because some of the Postgres intrinsics are only compiled into the Postgres server, and not available for linking from shared libs.

At present, the project's process is as follows:

- Build is run with `cargo build -v`.
- Failing call to `rustc` is copied and `-C link-args='-Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup'` added to it.
- Success!

This seems like a hard sell for automation. What options are available for adding codegen flags to Rust builds through `cargo`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`cargo` provides `rustc` command which allows one to pass arbitrary compiler flags. The following should do it:

```
% cargo rustc -- -C link-args='-Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup'
```

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. I'm not sure about accepting this, though, because it doesn't provide a way to document and automate the build process.

Comment: This is really the only way to do anything close, so time to accept.

Comment: No way to put it to toml file? At all?

Comment: @MajesticRa, nope, and Cargo is explicitly designed [against it](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/60#issuecomment-51705597). Access to a subset of compiler configuration controlled by the flags is provided via [`[profile]`](http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html#the-profile-sections) section in the manifest.

Comment: Ah... It was 2 years ago. The times when Rust had classes and garbage collector as I recall))) I mean... Rust concepts where changing rapidly before 1.0